# Connect form to my SQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to have this form submit to a database but I am having no luck. I am a complete newbie and based this code off another form that is already in use. Can anyone spot errors that would make it not work properly? Any help would be huge.

```
<?php
include("includes/captcha.php");
if (!empty($_POST['submitcontestant'])) { 
$addcontestantsql = "INSERT INTO ".$config['db_dbpaper'].".contest (company, name, address, phone)";
$company = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['company']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$captcha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['captcha']);
<?php
include("includes/captcha.php");
if (!empty($_POST['submitcontestant'])) { 
$addcontestantsql = "INSERT INTO ".$config['db_dbpaper'].".contest (company, name, address, phone)";
$company = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['company']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$captcha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['captcha']);

$addcontestantsql .= " VALUES('$company', '$name', '$email', '$phone')";
$allowed = false;
if (empty($company) && empty($name) && empty($address) && empty ($email) && empty($phone)) {
    echo '<strong>Please go back and fill out all the fields!</strong>';
}
elseif ($captcha != $captchaans) {
    echo '<strong>CAPTCHA incorrect!</strong>';
}
else {
    $allowed = true;
    echo '<strong>You are in the contest!</strong>';
}
if ($allowed) {
    db_exec($addcontestantql);
}
}
?>
<?php 
$companysql = "SELECT DISTINCT company FROM ".$config['db_dbpaper'].".contest ";
$mainsql = "SELECT * FROM ".$config['db_dbpaper'].".contest ";
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
$companyname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['company']);
$mainsql .= "WHERE company like '$companyname'";
}
$company = db_list($companysql);
$contest = db_list($mainsql);
?>
<div id="fullwidthpage">

<h2>Contest</h2>
<p>Please fill the out form and then click submit. Thank you.</p>
<form method="post">
  <table width="491" border="0">
<tr>
  <td width="107">Company:</td>
  <td width="374"><input name="company" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Name:</td>
  <td><input name="name" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Email:</td>
  <td><input name="address" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Phone:</td>
  <td><input name="phone" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p><?php echo '<img src="'.BASE_URL.'images/captcha/'.date('n').'.jpg">'; ?><br />
          What color is this?:<br />
      <input name="captcha" size="25" style="text-transform: lowercase;"/>
      <input name="submitcontestant" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? Your `$addcontestantsql` statement is only displaying the back half of an `insert` statement. What error checking have your tried? Are you getting any error messages? Much more information is needed.

Comment: sorry didnt realize that that part didnt copy over, check it out now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All set, I was creating my data table in the wrong database, new table was added in the appropriate database and all better :). Thanks to everyone who gave me input!

Answer (score 0):

id suggest you to start here : https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php

you're way off track at the moment and basically asking someone to code it for you.

after your posts update : it seems that the problem is you're not connecting to sql at all try using $link = mysql_connect('host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

Comment: check it out now sorry I didnt realize it didnt copy over fully

Comment: In Dreamweaver there is no error, that's kind of why I am having trouble. This is the link to the actual form, its allows me to submit but it just doesn't show up in the data table. http://nerej.com/meded_contest

Comment: its not showing up cause you're not connected to the mySQL with your php use $link = mysql_connect('host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

Comment: @user3083724 I've updated the answer for your problem.